# Why does X220 Tablet rotation work with stilus only while touch input does not rotate with screen?

Tags: unity, touchscreen, wacom

I have a Lenovo x220 Tablet and have tried installing both Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 on it, both with unity, and both have the same problem. When I install with unity and try to use the touch screen things work once calibrated, but then when I rotate the screen 180 degrees the stylus input will rotate with the screen (i.e. when I touch somewhere on the screen with the pen the input will be directly under it still) but the touch input is mirrored so touching a point in the bottom left of the screen registers a click as if I touched the top right.

This problem does not exist in Ubuntu Gnome, both the touch and the stylus input rotate with the display if it is switched around in to laptop mode.

Why does the standard Ubuntu not rotate the touch input and is there any way to make it?